# using html source instead of actual aspx page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Somehow i have lost my source code but i have published project in precompile state on my hosted server. i am able to recover c# code using decompilers but unable to find the aspx pages code as they are in compiled form. when i view them in decompiler they just show me the C# code of aspx page which is not helping me.

Initially i decided to reconstruct them on the basis of GUI but its taking too much time. My questions is , is this possible i can use the html source of page instead of its actual aspx code ? i have the c# code for my page but no aspx code so if its possible just to copy the html in aspx file and try to run if this works?

Comment: How you lost the code, dont you use TFS or similar code control tools? if you deleted from hard disk you can use disk recovery softwares or check in ftp folders where you upload or shared folders

Comment: Thats an unfortunate and it happened. please suggest related to my question

Comment: Do you want to use generated html that is rendered in browser in place of server side aspx code that had server side controls like GridViews, DropDownList etc?

Comment: Yes i want to use generated html

Comment: Recovering aspx page code from html is not possible.

Comment: i also have converted c# code for aspx page .. is this possible to convert that code to aspx page again?